# Join two tables with different number of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, rows

I have two tables:

```
---------
|dogs   |
---------
|item_1 |
|       |
|       |
|       |
---------

---------
|cats   |
---------
|item_1 |
|item_2 |
|item_3 |
|item_4 |
---------
```

so I want to join the tables something like this:

```
------------------
|dogs   | cats   |
------------------
|item_1 | item1  |
|NULL   | item2  |
|NULL   | item3  |
|NULL   | item4  |
------------------
```

I use a condition in the second table, but if nothing is found I still want to get that single result from the first table something like this:

```
------------------
|dogs   | cats   |
------------------
|item_1 | NULL   |
------------------
```

The tables don't have ID fields, but I can also add an ID to make a relation between the items.

I already tried different solutions, but I can't get to keep the single result from the first table if nothing was found in the second table when using a condition (I get 0 rows), or I get repeated the item1 in the first table when I actually need Nulls.

Comment: For your third example, do you want something like item_5 instead of item_1? Otherwise your SQL statements (you tried) might help clarify the logic you want to try to implement.

Comment: In the third example I just want to get the single row from the first table, in case nothing is found from cats using a WHERE condition.

Comment: I think you want to do what therealmitchconnors suggests in his answer (so I'm giving it +1).

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from dogs left outer join cats
```

This will give you all dogs and any matching cats.  This means that the Cat columns could be null, but the dog columns can not.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Danny, I left out the on statement from the join because you didn't give me column names to join on.  To make the query work, add the following to the last line: ` on dogs.[dogscolumnname] = cats.[catscolumnname]` replacing the text in brackets with the appropriate column names.

Answer (score 0):

When you add id's to both tables, you can use [SQL left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to match all the data from the right table to the left table.

From W3Schools:

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).

Comment: OK but let's suppose I don't have IDs in both tables?

Comment: Then you have to join on another field that's available in both tables. But I advise you to use id's, it's much easier, also in the future.

Comment: But in this case both tables have nothing in common.

Comment: Then it's quite difficult to join on these tables, because the database needs to know which fields belong together.